# Not able to pass data from view to Controller via url

Tags: codeigniter-3, php-7

I am new to CodeIgniter and trying to pass data from view to controller, and then access it. I have looked for various solutions but none of them worked for me. Can you please help in letting me know where am I wrong?

the URL helper is loaded automatically, and I don't understand what else to do.

view.php

```
 ...
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'product/'.$id; ?> 
...
```

Controller.php

```
class Product extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($id){

       $id = $this->uri->segment(2);
        echo "hello";
          echo $id;
    }

}
```

the expected result is to print Hello but instead it shows 404 Page not found. 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just remove $id = $this->uri->segment(2);

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to the answer.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'index/product/'.$id; ?>
```

prints the correct output. It is so because i did the url_routing in my site. Thanks for the help by the way.